# Markers are not properly aligned with path in d3 with leaflet

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm creating d3 markers(flights) and paths(trails) over leaflet map. Input data of Path's endpoint and marker's Geo-location(latitude, longitude) are same but they are not plotting on same location.

```js
var defaultlocation = [28.6139, 77.2090];
  var defaultzoom = 3;
  var map = L.map('map', {
    center: defaultlocation,
    zoom: defaultzoom,
    minZoom: 2
  });
var mbAttr = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> Contributors',
  mbUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

var mapTileLayer = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
  attribution: mbAttr
});

map.addLayer(mapTileLayer);

map._initPathRoot();

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).select(".leaflet-zoom-animated");

var trails = [{"type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[28.320282,74.448219],
        [28.31662,74.290764], 
        [28.312931,74.137733],
        [28.309067,73.978165],
        [28.304831,73.820801],
        [28.300409,73.661285],
        [28.295382,73.444893],
        [28.294729,73.425507],
        [27.648056,67.771759],
        [27.637573,67.736671],
        [27.596539,67.599617],
        [27.552593,67.452942],
        [27.511908,67.317772],
        [27.470032,67.179688],
        [27.426956,67.021629],
        [27.403152,66.867195],
        [27.371367,66.663139],
        [27.368317,66.643532],
        [27.345901,66.500511],
        [27.321136,66.344162],
        [27.281473,66.09417],
        [27.257034,65.942268],
        [27.18718,65.515411],
        [27.159088,65.345146],
        [27.144058,65.254333],
        [27.122776,65.12706],
        [27.097359,64.976524],
        [27.070406,64.817642],
        [27.045547,64.671494],
        [27.020128,64.522865],
        [26.995422,64.380249],
        [26.967957,64.227058],
        [26.964386,64.205864],
        [26.961731,64.190941],
        [26.958115,64.17601],
        [26.951279,64.155296],
        [26.94548,64.141762],
        [26.938797,64.128754],
        [26.879791,64.056152],
        [26.783798,63.950172],
        [26.688538,63.845356],
        [26.58783,63.734749],
        [26.49353,63.631466],
        [26.39859,63.527718],
        [26.303101,63.423916],
        [26.208252,63.321259],
        [26.113012,63.218185],
        [26.018698,63.115242],
        [25.924072,63.013226],
        [25.828766,62.910358],
        [25.733564,62.80827],
        [25.634903,62.70274],
        [25.53907,62.600357],
        [25.44359,62.498528],
        [25.348764,62.397732],
        [25.252945,62.296192],
        [25.153061,62.190655],
        [25.05835,62.090607],
        [24.963226,61.990559],
        [24.862852,61.884949],
        [24.727203,61.729633],
        [24.696304,61.653393],
        [24.62632,61.456017],
        [24.584427,61.313831],
        [24.582235,61.274174],
        [24.582642,61.125286],
        [24.582933,60.970287],
        [24.583008,60.818176],
        [24.582561,60.668732],
        [24.581863,60.656242],
        [24.579489,60.636238],
        [24.576975,60.622456],
        [24.546249,60.539043],
        [24.490585,60.410664],
        [24.432953,60.278675],
        [24.37587,60.148212],
        [24.321262,60.02396],
        [24.265028,59.895905],
        [24.209492,59.769821],
        [24.157446,59.65229],
        [24.103088,59.529675],
        [24.04953,59.409382],
        [23.998981,59.296062],
        [23.948273,59.181976],
        [23.896957,59.073841],
        [23.845638,58.969429],
        [23.820465,58.917797],
        [23.797989,58.871765],
        [23.773499,58.822124],
        [23.751297,58.777264],
        [23.727163,58.728455],
        [23.718319,58.710522],
        [23.709707,58.693161],
        [23.701094,58.675751],
        [23.693087,58.659737],
        [23.685266,58.643673],
        [23.678055,58.62859],
        [23.669065,58.609676],
        [23.664225,58.598484],
        [23.659698,58.586224],
        [23.654846,58.570251],
        [23.651796,58.553085],
        [23.648987,58.536785],
        [23.646116,58.519817],
        [23.643137,58.50256],
        [23.640064,58.485718],
        [23.637131,58.469288],
        [23.634338,58.453278],
        [23.633127,58.446228],
        [23.631824,58.438663],
        [23.630539,58.431446],
        [23.628159,58.418072],
        [23.625866,58.405289],
        [23.624748,58.39933],
        [23.623585,58.393009],
        [23.622528,58.387501],
        [23.62149,58.38171],
        [23.620512,58.376217],
        [23.618418,58.364815],
        [23.61731,58.359222],
        [23.616137,58.353519],
        [23.614929,58.347675],
        [23.613052,58.338573],
        [23.611176,58.326874],
        [23.610764,58.320618],
        [23.610168,58.308918],
        [23.609711,58.303272],
        [23.608749,58.292492],
        [23.607834,58.28186],
        [23.607384,58.276409],
        [23.606733,58.26796],
        [23.60643,58.264294],
        [23.606127,58.260551],
        [23.606037,58.259533],
        [23.605988,58.258877],
        [23.605968,58.258564],
        [23.605797,58.258221],
        [23.605534,58.258141],
        [23.605053,58.258171],
        [23.604673,58.258205],
        [23.604275,58.258247],
        [23.604012,58.258274],
        [23.603634,58.258312],
        [23.60338,58.25853],
        [23.603394,58.258961],
        [23.603451,58.259556],
        [23.603533,58.260719],
        [23.6036,58.261402],
        [23.603703,58.262737],
        [23.603748,58.263424],
        [23.603863,58.264809],
        [23.603987,58.266224],
        [23.604033,58.266861],
        [23.60408,58.267529],
        [23.604137,58.268105],
        [23.604172,58.268661],
        [23.604219,58.269138],
        [23.604263,58.26973],
        [23.604286,58.2701],
        [23.604343,58.270695],
        [23.604378,58.271053],
        [23.604401,58.27137],
        [23.604393,58.271679],
        [23.604265,58.271938],
        [23.60368,58.272057],
        [23.603222,58.272095],
        [23.602707,58.272144],
        [23.602194,58.272198],
        [23.601124,58.272301],
        [23.60059,58.27235],
        [23.600006,58.2724],
        [23.598948,58.272507],
        [23.598392,58.272552],
        [23.597876,58.272598],
        [23.59742,58.27264],
        [23.59679,58.272705],
        [23.596401,58.272743],
        [23.596062,58.272781],
        [23.595737,58.272793],
        [23.595337,58.272884],
        [23.595177,58.273106],
        [23.5952,58.273582],
        [23.595222,58.273918],
        [23.595257,58.274242],
        [23.59528,58.274624],
        [23.595316,58.274971],
        [23.595348,58.275425],
        [23.595444,58.276562],
        [23.595491,58.27721],
        [23.595543,58.277817],
        [23.595583,58.278442],
        [23.595646,58.279087],
        [23.595703,58.279865],
        [23.595795,58.28101],
        [23.59584,58.281582],
        [23.595898,58.282211],
        [23.595943,58.282825],
        [23.596025,58.28392],
        [23.596069,58.284454],
        [23.596115,58.284912],
        [23.596149,58.285435],
        [23.596184,58.285904],
        [23.59623,58.2864],
        [23.59627,58.28685],
        [23.596298,58.287251],
        [23.598482,58.289104]]
    },{"type": "LineString",
      "coordinates":[[23.953314,83.35218],[23.860163,83.393333],[23.723557,83.44162],[23.591324,83.505318],[23.441519,83.579308],[23.307123,83.645531],[23.116911,83.739166],[23.096466,83.749229],[22.967926,83.812202],[22.834663,83.877357],[22.699539,83.943436],[22.568069,84.007507],[22.426495,84.076332],[22.292999,84.141045],[22.160774,84.204964],[22.029465,84.268486],[21.892868,84.334251],[21.762985,84.396721],[21.626541,84.462341],[21.496948,84.524216],[21.365707,84.586937],[21.228104,84.652855],[21.08835,84.719444],[20.956375,84.782425],[20.82756,84.843048],[20.690933,84.907738],[20.561285,84.968964],[20.433243,85.029518],[20.298964,85.092758],[20.170715,85.153114],[20.036545,85.215599],[19.912537,85.27372],[19.782234,85.334755],[19.654634,85.394829],[19.522568,85.452835],[19.394806,85.524643],[19.277618,85.629456],[19.172678,85.736053],[19.062582,85.847816],[18.958958,85.952934],[18.849234,86.064346],[18.74519,86.169815],[18.637049,86.279427],[18.534073,86.383781],[18.432358,86.486824],[18.327431,86.597382],[18.229523,86.703804],[18.216217,86.719131],[18.206905,86.730667],[18.198029,86.742996],[18.186356,86.761826],[18.1793,86.77507],[18.137264,86.903374],[18.098328,87.055084],[18.073471,87.221474],[17.365723,88.518433],[17.331848,88.543541],[17.202026,88.639381],[17.07699,88.731567],[14.209305,92.040993],[14.101558,92.154861],[13.957664,92.306549],[13.864001,92.401184],[13.830437,92.434822],[13.728255,92.53717],[13.546282,92.719162],[12.948691,93.313538],[12.891944,93.369766],[11.131302,95.441971],[11.065475,95.537491],[10.976257,95.666954],[10.888412,95.794151],[10.798536,95.924332],[10.673823,96.104881],[10.635681,96.16011],[10.54492,96.290688],[10.458939,96.414528],[10.368576,96.544403],[10.27803,96.67466],[10.189866,96.801437],[10.022507,97.041214],[10.01207,97.05513],[9.989552,97.082344],[9.911809,97.15229],[9.900284,97.16127],[9.888748,97.169884],[9.870983,97.182076],[9.859485,97.188896],[9.840775,97.198143],[9.828667,97.203003],[9.815679,97.207413],[9.679793,97.226067],[9.540161,97.243622],[9.400107,97.267738],[9.261335,97.29113],[9.121818,97.312347],[8.986588,97.326485],[8.834793,97.342262],[8.815247,97.344498],[8.801926,97.346359],[8.786453,97.349205],[8.7683,97.354019],[8.755188,97.358559],[8.665237,97.410095],[8.541412,97.48951],[8.416086,97.569771],[8.291931,97.649559],[8.177124,97.735352],[8.078629,97.851913],[7.9818,97.971291],[7.89006,98.084259],[7.792984,98.203758],[7.696426,98.322517],[7.603982,98.436172],[7.507805,98.55584],[7.427456,98.687012],[7.350924,98.812881],[7.27034,98.943665],[7.193298,99.067841],[7.112732,99.197929],[7.032806,99.327438],[6.956863,99.450806],[6.875765,99.583153],[6.797837,99.710777],[6.791519,99.720856],[6.698593,99.832718],[6.594823,99.947311],[6.477356,100.077393],[6.463127,100.092361],[6.441294,100.112869],[6.363327,100.167053],[6.147949,100.292419],[6.08596,100.32843],[5.963196,100.39991],[5.83342,100.475418],[5.704558,100.550377],[5.581787,100.62159],[5.451313,100.697372],[5.328644,100.768509],[5.197449,100.84462],[5.069229,100.918968],[4.944546,100.991203],[4.815224,101.066071],[4.691528,101.13781],[4.562771,101.212303],[4.440664,101.282913],[4.25655,101.38932],[4.220612,101.410057],[4.092919,101.483841],[3.965226,101.557617],[3.837708,101.631218],[3.710493,101.704605],[3.53627,101.805275],[3.449754,101.855667],[3.330487,101.92495],[3.206497,101.997162],[3.069992,102.076485],[3.052505,102.087006],[3.030411,102.102531],[3.015095,102.114845],[2.928927,102.214287],[2.84436,102.323265],[2.753448,102.43885],[2.655246,102.559029],[2.64061,102.573944],[2.568101,102.622063],[2.547013,102.634232],[2.528066,102.647064],[2.518755,102.654121],[2.428299,102.768578],[2.403763,102.823837],[2.345078,102.956093],[2.291301,103.077423],[2.235672,103.203842],[2.181438,103.325706],[2.118027,103.442375],[2.034668,103.550613],[1.955334,103.653877],[1.87829,103.754028],[1.839615,103.803856],[1.793937,103.862991],[1.787018,103.872101],[1.776387,103.885864],[1.768985,103.89373],[1.758371,103.903107],[1.710702,103.926735],[1.658842,103.943451],[1.604376,103.961021],[1.585476,103.966988],[1.566157,103.973091],[1.546921,103.97908],[1.526596,103.985458],[1.510529,103.990486],[1.493408,103.995834],[1.477066,104.001007],[1.461414,104.00605],[1.446611,104.010788],[1.432068,104.015526],[1.417702,104.0196],[1.402572,104.022766],[1.387985,104.025307],[1.373383,104.027817],[1.35886,104.030487],[1.343124,104.03373],[1.329532,104.037071],[1.307513,104.042992],[1.297073,104.045509],[1.289916,104.046776],[1.278809,104.047554],[1.271481,104.046684],[1.264572,104.044441],[1.256287,104.038574],[1.252302,104.033234],[1.249878,104.026978],[1.249283,104.020554],[1.251526,104.011383],[1.252899,104.008965],[1.259079,104.003006],[1.2692,103.997864],[1.274135,103.995445],[1.279023,103.99308],[1.286238,103.989571],[1.294235,103.985687],[1.301102,103.982521],[1.30607,103.980766],[1.31133,103.979958],[1.316916,103.98053],[1.32193,103.982147],[1.326416,103.983963]]}];

var markers = [{lat: 28.320282, lng: 74.448219, rotate: 88},{lat: 23.953314, lng: 83.35218, rotate: 318}];

function update(){
  d3.selectAll('.markersgroup').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.trailsgroup').remove();

  var trailsgroup = svg.append("g").attr("class","trailsgroup");
  var markersgroup = svg.append("g").attr("class","markersgroup");

  var marker = markersgroup.selectAll(".marker")
    .data(markers)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "marker");

  marker.append("path")
    .attr("class", "flight")
    .attr("d", "m25.21488,3.93375c-0.44355,0 -0.84275,0.18332 -1.17933,0.51592c-0.33397,0.33267 -0.61055,0.80884 -0.84275,1.40377c-0.45922,1.18911 -0.74362,2.85964 -0.89755,4.86085c-0.15655,1.99729 -0.18263,4.32223 -0.11741,6.81118c-5.51835,2.26427 -16.7116,6.93857 -17.60916,7.98223c-1.19759,1.38937 -0.81143,2.98095 -0.32874,4.03902l18.39971,-3.74549c0.38616,4.88048 0.94192,9.7138 1.42461,13.50099c-1.80032,0.52703 -5.1609,1.56679 -5.85232,2.21255c-0.95496,0.88711 -0.95496,3.75718 -0.95496,3.75718l7.53,-0.61316c0.17743,1.23545 0.28701,1.95767 0.28701,1.95767l0.01304,0.06557l0.06002,0l0.13829,0l0.0574,0l0.01043,-0.06557c0,0 0.11218,-0.72222 0.28961,-1.95767l7.53164,0.61316c0,0 0,-2.87006 -0.95496,-3.75718c-0.69044,-0.64577 -4.05363,-1.68813 -5.85133,-2.21516c0.48009,-3.77545 1.03061,-8.58921 1.42198,-13.45404l18.18207,3.70115c0.48009,-1.05806 0.86881,-2.64965 -0.32617,-4.03902c-0.88969,-1.03062 -11.81147,-5.60054 -17.39409,-7.89352c0.06524,-2.52287 0.04175,-4.88024 -0.1148,-6.89989l0,-0.00476c-0.15655,-1.99844 -0.44094,-3.6683 -0.90277,-4.8561c-0.22699,-0.59493 -0.50356,-1.07111 -0.83754,-1.40377c-0.33658,-0.3326 -0.73578,-0.51592 -1.18194,-0.51592l0,0l-0.00001,0l0,0z");

  marker.attr("transform", function (d) {
    var cord = map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.lat, d.lng]);
    var bb = d3.select(this).node().getBBox();
    return "translate(" + (cord.x - (bb.width/2)) + "," + (cord.y - (bb.height/2)) + ") scale(0.6,0.6) rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
    });

  function projectPoint(x, y) {
    var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(x, y));
    this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
  }

  var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint});
  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

  trails.forEach(element => {
    trailsgroup.append("path")
    .datum(element)
    .attr("class", "trail")
    .attr("d", path);
  });

}
update();
map.on("viewreset", function () {
        update();
    });
    map.on("moveend", function () {
        update();
    });
```

```css
html,
  body,
  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .flight {
    fill :yellow;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
  }


  .trail {
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

I have tried to transform markers like this, but i think it still need corrections with scale and angle.

```
marker.attr("transform", function (d) {
                var cord = map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.lat, d.lng]);
                var bb = d3.select(this).node().getBBox();
                return "translate(" + (cord.x - (bb.width/2)) + "," + (cord.y - (bb.height/2)) + ") scale(0.6,0.6) rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
              });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qj3aoug5/) d3 Markers are not plotting on correct position on map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a `matrix` transformation on the path or by doing the following:

Apply the rotation on the `path` and translation on the `group` as such - In order to rotate around the centre you will first need to move the plane to a negative location where the centre of rotation is in the middle and use the same translation values when rotating (you should variables or calculate the bbox)

```
marker.append("path")
  .attr("class", "flight"
  .attr('transform', d => `translate(-25, -30)rotate(${d.rotate}, 25, 30)`)
```

after applying the rotation on the plane you can apply the translation on the group marker as such:

```
marker.attr("transform", function (d) {
  var cord = map.latLngToLayerPoint([d.lat, d.lng]);
  var bb = d3.select(this).node().getBBox();
  return `translate(${cord.x}, ${cord.y})`;
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cstefanache/nsv6b4ta/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This works perfectly.